# changeColor() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why am I getting an error in `getCar()` function where I set `changeColor()`?

```js
function Car(model, color, price) {
  this.model = model;
  this.color = color;
  this.price = price;

  this.changeColor = function() {
    console.log(this);
    this.color = 'Blue';
  };

  this.getCar = function() {
    changeColor();
    return console.log(`Model: ${this.model} Color: ${this.color} Price: ${this.price}`);
  };
}

const mitsubishi = new Car('Mitsubishi', 'Black', 1991);

mitsubishi.getCar();
```

Answer (score 0):

change the way how you invoke `changeColor()`.

change:

```js
this.getCar = function() {
  changeColor()  
  console.log(`Model: ${this.model} Color: ${this.color} Price: ${this.price}` ) 
}
```

to:

```js
this.getCar = function() {
  this.changeColor()  
  console.log(`Model: ${this.model} Color: ${this.color} Price: ${this.price}` ) 
}
```

please note that i dropped the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `changeColor()` to `this.changeColor()`.

```js
function Car(model, color, price) {
    this.model = model
    this.color = color
    this.price = price

     this.changeColor = function(){
        //console.log(this)
        this.color = 'Blue'
    }

    this.getCar = function() {
        this.changeColor()  
      return console.log(`Model: ${this.model} Color: ${this.color} Price: ${this.price}` ) 
    }
}

const myCar = new Car("Ford", "Orange", "10,000");
console.log("Original Car:");
console.log(myCar.model, myCar.color, myCar.price)
console.log("\nmyCar.getCar():");
myCar.getCar();
```